# Using gwidgets, is there a way to focus ginput and the like windows?

Tags: r, gwidgets

I would like to get user input using `ginput("type in information")`. Is there a way to focus on that window like it is possible with:

```
win <- gwindow("window")
focus(win)
```

?

Maybe add a handler to `ginput()`?

Comment: For RGtk2, the focus should be in the input box. For tcltk, I just pushed changes for gWidgets2tcltk and gWidgetstcltk to the developmental sites (GitHub and r-forge) to have focus set on the entry box. In general, you can't call a method like focus on a modal dialog, and the handler is only called after the user clicks a button. I'd have to expose more of the dialog creation process to have control over this.

Comment: thanks - that makes sense, more exposing means less convenience for those simple dialogues.